# using GROUP_CONCAT in MySQL Transaction

Tags: mysql

I am learning to use MySQL so will appreciate help on this topic.

I will try to explain my situation first. My Query involves 4 tables and i want to do an Left Outer Join on **JOIN1** from Table 1 *Products* & 2 *Product_meta* WITH **JOIN2** from Table 3 *SalesCoupons* & 4 *SalesCoupons_Product*

*Product_meta* is a table that contains a lot of data regarding Products. In Concern with current situation, it has *Product_Category_id* and *product_id* (foreign key to Products.id)

SalesCoupons stores coupons for discount on Product Category but, only some Products will be on discount, % derived from SalesCoupons_Product Table.

SalesCoupons store *Product_Category* (foreign key to Product_meta.Product_Category_id) AND status of Discount *status_id* (where status 3 means Discount No longer Available)

SalesCoupons_Product stores *SalesCoupons_id* (foreign key to SalesCoupons.id) & *Product_id* (foreign key to Products.id) & *Discount_prc* as percentage of discount

Now, I need to create a Report that shows Products not discounted in any given Product Category

Here is what i wrote

```
BEGIN;
SET @products_not_discounted := (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(scp.product_id) FROM SalesCoupons_Product scp, SalesCoupons sc WHERE scp.SalesCoupons_id=sc.id AND sc.status_id<3 AND sc.product_category_id=:product_category_id GROUP BY scp.SalesCoupons_id);
SELECT p.id,p.name FROM Products p, Product_meta pm WHERE pm.product_id=p.id AND pm.product_category_id=:product_category_id AND p.id NOT IN (@products_not_discounted);
COMMIT;
```

My Issue is that i do not seem to be able to use GROUP_CONCAT inside MySQL Transaction

For example, if Ids for Products not on Discount comes as 15,25,35,48 then Result of Query will consider 15 to be ignored but not any of the rest

I have created another solution that uses nested SQL but would like to understand why Transaction did not work

The Query for Solution that worked for me is as follows :

```
SELECT p.id,p.name,
       (SELECT Discount_prc FROM SalesCoupons_Product scp,SalesCoupons sc WHERE scp.SalesCoupons_id=sc.id AND sc.status_id<3 AND scp.product_id=p.id ORDER BY scp.id DESC LIMIT 1) as Discount_prc
FROM Products p, Product_meta pm
WHERE pm.product_id=p.id AND pm.product_category_id=:product_category_id
HAVING Discount_prc IS NULL;
```

Comment: `FROM Products p, Product_meta pm`  Use a `INNER JOIN` clause the comma join syntax is over 30 years old..

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesnt have anything to do with transactions.

This comparison does not works as you intent

```
NOT IN (@products_not_discounted);
```

`@products_not_discounted` is just an string even when have separated values with commma

instead you do

```
NOT IN ( SELECT cp.product_id FROM SalesCoupons_Product scp ... )
```